# ¿Porque tengo el error Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)?

Tags: latex

Estoy definiendo un comando para una sección de un CV, de la siguiente manera:

```
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1] {
    \vspace{10pt}
    \textbf{\Large{\textcolor{darkcol}{\uppercase{#1}}}}\\[-4pt]
        \textcolor{maincol}{ \rule{0.1\textwidth}{2pt} } \\
    }
```

pero me da el error:
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000).

¿Alguien sabe poque, como arreglarlo o en su defecto como ignoralo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo hacia falta agragar \vspace{5pt} al final.

```
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1] {
    \vspace{10pt}
    \textbf{\Large{\textcolor{darkcol}{\uppercase{#1}}}}\\[-4pt]
        \textcolor{maincol}{ \rule{0.1\textwidth}{2pt} } 
    \vspace{10pt}
    }
```